# Using SciPy chi-square inside a function that is applied to a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, function, scipy

I have a data frame that has two numeric columns 'observed' and 'expected'. I want to write a function to calculate chi-square of these values for each row. Now, I want to use SciPy already defined chisqaure in the function as follows:

```
def chi_2(df, observed, expected):
    obs = np.array(df[observed])
    exp = np.array(df[expected])
    chi = scipy.stats.chisquare(obs, exp)[0]
            
    return chi

df_f2['chi_2'] = chi_2(df_f2, 'observed', 'expected')
```

However, when I do so, I get the same value repeated for all rows. But if I replaced SciPy function with chi = ((obs-exp)**2)/exp, all work fine.

```
def chi_2(df, observed, expected):
    obs = np.array(df[observed])
    exp = np.array(df[expected])
    chi = ((obs-exp)**2)/exp
    
    return chi
```

But I don't understand why. Could you please explain it to me? It would be much better for me to use the already defined SciPy functions inside than writing the expressions my self.
Thanks

Comment: I believe `scipy.stats.chisquare` gives you the aggregate (here sum) of the values from your second function. so if you do `chi_2(df_f2, 'observed', 'expected').sum()` with your second function, you should retrieve `scipy.stats.chisquare(obs, exp)[0]`?

Comment: i don't believe this is the problem. i had the same problem with a completely different function. and i tried to use what you suggested, but it didn't work. i even tried df_f2['kstest']= df_f2.apply(lambda x: chisquare(df_f2.observed, df_f2.expected)[1], axis=1), and it gave me the same result.

Comment: Your first version of `chi_2()` applies the test once, using the first column as `f_obs` and the second column as `f_exp` in the call of `chisquare()`. Try something like `print(chi_2(df_f2, 'observed', 'expected'))` to confirm this.

Comment: I can see it is applied once, but i don't understand why. What is the difference between using the SciPy function of chi_square and between writing it myself that makes the code not working in the first case and working in the second?

Comment: [`scipy.stats.chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) is *designed* to accept two 1-d vectors and return the (scalar) test statistic χ², as in the [formula in the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic); note the summation over all the terms.  In your second version of `chi_2()`, you use a Python expression of NumPy arrays, which is evaluated element-wise, and there is no summation.

Comment: Thanks Warren, i think i understand now. i need to iterate over the two columns, even though it is much slower. Thanks.

Comment: Note that there is no meaningful reason to apply the chi-squared test when you have just one observed count and one expected count.  `scipy.stats.chisquare` requires the sum of the observed and expected frequencies to be equal, so unless the observed and expected value are the same, you'll get an error. If they *are* the same, the χ² statistic will be 0.